# How to limit the amount of memory that OS X uses?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, memory

In linux, one can use the `mem=xxxx` boot argument to specify how much memory the OS can use.  For example, if you say `mem=2048` the OS will believe that your computer has 2048 GB of ram regardless of how much physical memory you actually have.  (

Is there a way to do this?  My Macbook (running Mountain Lion) has 8GB of ram, but I need to boot with only 2GB of ram in order to install something via wine.  How can I make the OS believe that I have less memory than I actually have?

EDIT:  To be more specific, I'm trying to run the game "Lego Racers 2" on my Mac, using wine (because it is a windows only game).  According to this link (http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=8811) (and some other sources that I've seen):  "You cannot complete install if you have 3 or more gigs of RAM installed. The same problem exists in windows xp sp3 and vista sp1. Once installed you can add more ram."